# Input cursor doesn't flash when it gets focus in vue

Tags: vuejs3

In the following code, which I have simplified to illustrate the issue, I select an item in the list and the selected value is shown in the console and the input received focus, but the cursor is not flashing (at least not in Chrome or Firefox). However, it definitely has focus because it accepts input when I type.

I have made a second example, the button which executes `focusOnInput()` and even though this is using the same `inputRef.value.focus();` the focus works properly and the cursor flashes in the input.

```
<template>

    <select name="list" v-model="listModel">
        <option value="Item1">Item 1</option>
        <option value="Item2">Item 2</option>
        <option value="Item3">Item 3</option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" ref="inputRef" />

    <button @click="focusOnInput">Click</button>

</template>
  
  
<script setup>


    import { ref, watch } from 'vue'

    const listModel = ref('')
    const inputRef = ref('')

    watch(listModel, (newVal) => {
        console.log(newVal)
        inputRef.value.focus();
    })

    function focusOnInput() {
        inputRef.value.focus();
    }

</script>
```

I have tried adding the focus command within a nextTick but that doesn't seem to make any difference, the input still focuses without the cursor flashing.

Comment: are you using any kind of CSS framework?  only thing I can imagine is some styling making it hard to see the cursor.  try setting some padding in the input or setting a [text-indent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-indent) property.  It doesn't appear to be an issue when using just Vue by itself: [sandbox example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-script-setup-with-vite-cn1dlz?file=src%2FApp.vue)

Comment: Thank you for your reply @yoduh - thank you for creating that sandbox example. I think I was mistaken in one aspect because the problem is only happening in Chrome, it's fine in Firefox. If I use your sandbox example in Chrome then I get the issue of the cursor displaying but not flashing when I choose an item from the select, but when I press the button the cursor flashes. That rules out a CSS issue (I'd already disabled tailwind anyway). I think it could be a browser issue, but if it's working for other people in Chrome then it might just be a affecting Chrome on my own OS (which is Ubuntu).